# Compare a symbol from multibyte string with one in ASCII

Tags: php, string, encoding

I want to detect a space or a hyphen in a multibyte string.
At first I splitting a string into array of chars

```php
$chrArray = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Then I try to compare those symbols with a hyphen or a space

```php
foreach ($chrArray as $char) {
    if ($char == '-' || $char == ' ') {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Oh, this one doesn't work. Ok, why? Maybe because those symbols in ASCII?

```php
echo mb_detect_encoding('-'); // ASCII
```

Okay, I'll try to handle it.

```php
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($str); // UTF-8
    $dash = mb_convert_encoding('-', $encoding);
    $space = mb_convert_encoding(' ', $encoding);
```

Oh, but it doesn't work too. Wait a second...

```php
echo mb_detect_encoding($dash); // ASCII
```

!!! What's happening??? How could I do what I want?

Comment: Well, it worked for me - when I defined `$str` as a string with some non-ASCII symbols right in the source AND stored this source with UTF-8 encoding. I wonder how do you get this `$str` in your example?

Comment: `$str` comes from the POST request and in UTF-8, PHP source is in UTF-8 too. I wonder how there could be strings in ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to using regexes. This one

```php
"/(?<=-| |^)([\w]*)/u"
```

finds all words in unicode that have either a hyphen, or a space, or nothing (first in a line) at previous position. Instead of iterating chars array I'm using the `preg_replace_callback` (in PHP >= 5.4.1 the `mb_ereg_replace_callback` can be used).